# PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory should honor @Primary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

With the configuration below, I'm facing a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` at `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory()`:556

```
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oneEmf(...) {
    return ( abstracted as not relevant );
}
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean twoEmf(...) {
    return ( abstracted as not relevant );
}
```

Then I configured a Dao with the `@PersistenceContext`annotation

```
@PersistenceContext
protected void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}
```

It simple do find both EntityManagerFactory beans and throw the exception.
I'm just wondering if `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` shouldn't try to decide taking into account the @Primary annotation, since is what I expected to happen. The code says otherwise, did anyone had similar problem?